# How to remove border with css in the pageviewer webpart?

Tags: page-viewer-web-part

I have created a custom webpart. Inside this custom webpart I have an pageviewer webpart. This pageviewer webpart is showing the survey questions (http://myCompany.com/Lists/TestSurvey/NewForm.aspx?isdlg=0). I see now a border which is comming from the page (NewForm.aspx) which is loaded in the pageviewer webpart. I would like to inject some css in this page programmatically (c#, css, jQuery or javascript). Is there some solution to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. I used jQuery. I get the iframe and set custom css to the header of the source. The function SetCssInIframe() will executed after the page is loaded.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function SetCssInIframe()
    {
        var head = jQuery("#SurveyIfr").contents().find("head");
                var css = '<style type="text/css">' +
                          '.Mainstage{border:0 !important;}; ' +
                          '</style>';
                jQuery(head).append(css);
    }

    $(window).bind("load", function() {
       SetCssInIframe();
    });

</script>
```